# Haml novice cannot add an unordered list to page

Tags: html-lists, haml

I want to add three fields that will be used as counters to the top of the screen on my app. The following code does actually work, HOWEVER, if you put the page in edit mode and then click the "Save" button, the three counter fields disappear and stay that way until you refresh the browser. I am a Haml newbie, and there isn't much documentation out there, and what little there is did not help me.

Here is the relevant Haml code to render the page in question:

```
- form_for [@application, @item_collection], :html => { 'data-remote' => 'json', :id => 'edit_item_collection', :class => 'show_progress inline_edit' } do |f|
  = render 'edit_fields', :f => f
  .submit.editing_only
    %button.default_action{ :type => 'submit',:id => 'Save'} Save`
```

And here is the Haml code for the actual page:

```
.field.large
  = f.label      :name, nil, 'data-help-id' => 'page_name'
  = f.text_field :name, disabled_if_unauthorized(@item_collection, :maxlength => 255, :title => "Edit Page")
  = f.error_message_on(:name, :css_class => 'error_message')
.field
  = f.label      :path, nil, 'data-help-id' => 'page_path'
  = f.text_field :path, disabled_if_unauthorized(@item_collection, { :maxlength => 255, :class => 'extra_margin', :title => "Edit Page" })
  = f.error_message_on(:path, :css_class => 'error_message')
.field.info
  = f.label      'Info'
  %ul.elements_count
    %li.elements_in_use{ :id => 'elements_in_use' }
    %li.unused_elements{ :id => 'unused_elements'}
    %li.undefined_elements{ :id => 'undefined_elements'}
```

When I click "Save," the elements_count unordered list disappears (but reappears if I refresh the browser). I know that the problem is that I need to put "= f." in front of these elements, but I don't see how to do that for lists.

Here is my JavaScript for populating the li elements:

```
function getElementCount() {
  var usage_element_total = $('.usage').size();
  var unused_element_total = $('.unused').size();
  var undefined_element_total = $('.undefined').size();
  $('#elements_in_use').html(usage_element_total + " Elements in use,");
  if (unused_element_total < 1) {
    $('#unused_elements').html(" 0 unused Elements,");
  } else {
    $('#unused_elements').html((unused_element_total-1) + " unused Elements,"); 
  }
  $('#undefined_elements').html(undefined_element_total + " undefined Elements");
}
```

Any help would be vastly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where is the Save button you describe clicking and what is triggered when you click it? How are the `li` elements populated? I suspect this is a Javascript thing and doesn’t have to do with Haml. The `=f` inserts output from a Rails form builder, but it’s not a problem to include your own markup as well.

Comment: I believe you are 100% correct. I have added the code for the Save button as well as my JavaScript for populating the li elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger the Javascript that populates the element counts whenever the form is updated. Presumably you’re calling `getElementCount` when the page loads, you could trigger it when the form is rendered:

```
$("form").bind("ajax:complete", getElementCount);
```

But I’m guessing a bit as to how things are wired together and maybe that won’t work for your situation.

Comment: I actually have this line in my JavaScript already: 

`$('body').load(getElementCount());`

but that does not appear to work.

Comment: Note: the more code you give the easier it is for people to help you. Change it to this: `$('body').load(function() { getElementCount(); });`. The problem with the way you wrote it is that `getElementCount` is called immediately; passing it inside a function means the function isn’t executed until the `onload` event has been triggered.

Comment: Sorry about not including that line of code earlier. I actually did not write this; I'm trying to clean up someone else's mess. Anyway, I tried your advice but it did not work either. This is very perplexing.